# Mongoose find and save not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

I am trying to find a particular user in the db using Mongoose, and save or ignore data depending upon same data being present or not.

But the html I want to send still contains `" "` at the `res.send()` that is, there is no change being reflected in the variable `html` after the `User.find()` function callback.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
var html = "";
app.post('/', function(req, res){

    var name_of_user = req.body.username;
    var userObject = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    });

    User.find({"username" : name_of_user}, function(err,docs) {
        if(docs.length) {
            console.log('Name exists already');
            html = '<i>' + userObject.username + '</i> is already a registered user!';
            html += '<br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Try again</a>';
        }
        else {
            userObject.save(function(err, user) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
            });
            html = 'Successfully signed up as <i>' + name_of_user +
                '</i>. Added <i>' + name_of_user + '</i> to the MongoDB database.';
            html += '<br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Go back</a>';
        }

        //console.log(docs);
    });

    res.send(html);

});
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `res.send(html)` is outside the callback, so it is called before the callback is even called. You have to move that call into the callbacks in order to rely on their results.

```
User.find({"username" : name_of_user}, function(err,docs) {
    if(docs.length) {
        console.log('Name exists already');
        html = '<i>' + userObject.username + '</i> is already a registered user!';
        html += '<br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Try again</a>';
        res.send(html);
    }
    else {
        userObject.save(function(err, user) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            html = 'Successfully signed up as <i>' + name_of_user +
                   '</i>. Added <i>' + name_of_user + '</i> to the MongoDB database.';
            html += '<br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Go back</a>';
            res.send(html);
        });
    }
});
```